# How to output elements inside of stack during RPN Calculating

Tags: c

I implemented an RPN Calculator in C. Now I want to output the current iteration meaning

> Iteration 1: Contents: [5, 5]

> Iteration 2: Contents: [25]

I am not quite sure how i am going to print them. I tried Printing them in the `main function`, but the output was coming

> Iteration 1: Contents: 5

> Iteration 2: Contents: 5

> 10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int stack[MAX_SIZE];
int top = 0;

void makeEmpty()
{
    top = 0;
}

bool isEmpty()
{
    return top == 0;
}

bool isFull()
{
    return top == MAX_SIZE;
}

void push(int value)
{
    stack[top++] = value;
}

int pop()
{


    if(isEmpty())
    {
        printf("Not enough operands in expression\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return stack[--top];
}

//adds 2 integers
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

//subtracts 2 integers
int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

//multiplies 2 integers
int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

//divides 2 integers
int divide(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    while(1)
    {
        //Emptying the stack before the user enters another expression
        makeEmpty();

        printf("Enter an RPN expression: ");

        //Reads expression from user
        scanf("%c", &ch);

        //parse all characters until a newline is reached
        while(1)
        {
            if(ch == '\n')
                break;

            //if character is an integer
            if(ch >= 48 && ch <= 57)
            {
                if(!isFull())
                {
                    //convert char to int and push integer onto stack
                    printf("Iteration %d: Contents: %d \n", (top+1), (ch-48));
                    push(ch - 48);
                }
                else
                {
                    //stack ran out of space, print error and exit program
                    printf("Expression is too complex\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

            }

            switch(ch)
            {
                case '+':
                    push(add(pop(), pop()));
                    break;
                case '-':
                    push(sub(pop(), pop()));
                    break;
                case '*':
                    push(mul(pop(), pop()));
                    break;
                case '/':
                    push(divide(pop(), pop()));
                    break;
                case '=':
                    printf("%d\n", pop());
                    break;
            }



            //get next character
            scanf("%c", &ch);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One possibility: pop the value on the stack into a variable; print the variable; push the value back onto the stack?  If you want to print more than element on the stack, you could pop the values into an array, print the array, and push the values from the array back onto the stack.  Or you could provide a function which has access to the stack internals that does the job for the user.

Comment: Your stack is an array and your occupancy length is maintained by `top`. Do you know how to iterate over an array with a loop and visit each slot therein. ?

Comment: Instead of `if(ch >= 48 && ch <= 57)` you should write either `if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')` or (better) `if(isdigit(ch))`

Comment: Similarly, instead of `ch - 48`,  write `ch - '0'`.

Comment: `sub(pop(), pop())` cannot work reliably, since you have no guarantee which order the `pop` will occur (there is no sequence point).  On some platforms, this is equivalent to `int a = pop(); int b = pop(); sub(a,b)`, while on others it will be `sub(b,a)`

Comment: Replace `while(1)` with `if(scanf("%c", &ch) == 1)` (and remove the `scanf` at the end of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily workaround it in your program without creating temporary stacks:

```
void print_stack(void)
{
    printf("[");
    for(int index = top -1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        printf("%d%s", stack[index], index ? ", " : "");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: In which part would you call the function?

Comment: Call when you want to display the stack. It is up ti you.